# Configuring winhttrack to download a website that using local storage access token

Tags: httrack

I faced a website that uses a **localstorage** access token when a user login and not using the cookies in the request header.

My question is how to configure **winhttrack** to use the **accesstoken from localstorage** to download webpages that require **authentication**.

PS: the website is behind CloudFront cdn.